# Changing an element within a vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, copy, const-correctness, const-iterator

I'm iterating through a set of elements within a vector of structures and want to change an element in one of the structures.  When I write to the element to change the value, the update isn't retained.  Here is what I have:

first, in a header file:

```
std::vector<Sched::ScheduledEvent_t> v_SchedEvents;
typedef std::vector<Sched::ScheduledEvent_t>::const_iterator event_iter;
```

then later in a .cpp module...

```
for (event_iter i = v_SchedEvents.begin(); i != v_SchedEvents.end(); ++i)
{
    ScheduledEvent_t event = *i;

    if(event.member == true) {
        event.member = false;
    }
}
```

The value of event.member for the given structure in the vector isn't staying false.  When returning to this loop, the conditional statement is run again.

Could it have anything to do with the typedef for the iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here.

1) You're making a copy:

```
ScheduledEvent_t event = *i;
```

`event` is a copy of the element in the vector. Modifing `event` won't affect it.

2) You are using a `const_iterator` which only allows reading the value, not changing it.

Use a `iterator` instead

```
typedef std::vector<Sched::ScheduledEvent_t>::iterator event_iter;
```

and use it directly:

```
if (i->member) { //  == true useless
    i->member = false;
}
```

Or a for-range loop if you have access to C++11 or more recent:

```
for (auto & event : v_SchedEvents) {
    if (event.member) {
        event.member = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `const_iterator` prevents the modification of the referenced value.

*iterator* : Behaves like **value_type***.

*const_iterator* : Behaves like **const_value_type***

```
vector<node> v;
v.push_back(node(10, 11));
for( std::vector<node>::const_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end() ; ++it ){
    node n = *it;
    n.member = 12;           //A local copy of node `*it`. So its ok to modify.
    n = node(10, 13);        //Okay since local Copy is not const
    //(*it).member = 12;     //error assignment of member 'node::a' in read-only object
    //*it = node(10, 13);    //error passing 'const node' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
}
for( std::vector<node>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end() ; ++it ){
    //cout << *it.a;
    node n = *it;
    n.a = 12;
    n = node(10, 13);      //No problem
    (*it).a = 12;          //No problem
    *it = node(10, 13);    //No problem
}
```

You are able to modify member value because you are getting a local copy of const_iterator referenced value by doing `ScheduledEvent_t event = *i;`

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple matter of reference type and local variable.

When You do

```
ScheduledEvent_t event = *i;
```

You are creating a simple local variable "event" and copying everything from the source where "i" is pointing to.

So, if you wish to change the element in the structure change your code from

```
event.member = false;
```

to

```
*i.member = false;
```

or (my preference)

```
i->member = false;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: A reference would also solve the problem, but you aren't explaining that at all, so why even mention it?

Comment: With parenthesis: `(*i).member = false;`

Comment: Disagree. Neither `*i.member = false;` nor `(*i).member = false;` would work.

Comment: You are right. I missed that. Thank you all for pointing that out.